# PowerShell Find Application Last Accessed date

Tags: windows, powershell, registry

I am trying to uninstall a program based on the last used/accessed date. I know there is property attribute that shows Accessed date.

How can I get the date *programtically* in PowerShell, so I can compare it against the requirement.

The only think I know is the **DisplayName** of the program from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`.

From there I can get **InstallLocation**, but I don't know the name of the **.exe** file, so don't know how to get that.

How can I get the path to `.exe` file for this program and get the date.

> **Input** = DisplayName
>   **OutPut** = Accessed Date

once I have the path, I can run

`Get-ChildItem "C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe" | select lastaccesstime`

```
LastAccessTime      
--------------      
8/17/2017 3:07:17 PM
```

> FoxitReader is just an example. The logic/code should cover other
>   applications as well like Photoshop.

[image]

Comment: That is a file system property that tells you when that file was accessed. It doesn't tell you the last time someone opened that program.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Oh! I thought they were the same. What I want is last used date of this program. Thanks